# When we simplify trig identities, why would the value of sin(x)+ disappear?

Tags: calculus

Trying not to muddle the scope of my [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578151/trig-identities-simplify), so needing to ask another.

I begin with this equation:

$$\frac{\sin\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)\cdot \:\tan\left(x\right)^2}{\tan\left(x\right)}$$

and then all answers provided, change the equation to:

$$\frac{\sin(x) \, (1 + \tan^{2}(x))}{\tan(x)}$$

I am baffled with what happened to the $sin(x) +$ that is in the original equation.

I can see how this part changed :$$sin(x)(tan(x)^2 =  sin(x)(1 + \tan^{2}(x))$$

Just that elusive $sin(x) +$...lol what the hell happened to it?? I tested on my calculator, $sin(x) != 1 $ that it is just left out.

[Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/system-of-equations-calculator/simplify%20sin%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%2Bsin%5Cleft(x%5Cright)tan%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D) doesn't even give the right answer.

My lecturer said via email it was much easier to show me this but, his working out doesn't address my question.

[image]

Comment: $a+ab=a(1+b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: It didn't disappear. It just merely 'became' the number '1' because you factorized $\sin x$ out.

Comment: Kavi for president! What a simple explanation and my lecturer, couldn't just write that lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original expression is basically of the form

$$\frac{a+ab^2}{b}$$

with $a=\sin(x),b=\tan(x)$. All that happened in the simplification is factoring out $a$ (or $\sin(x)$) in the numerator, since $a+ab^2 = a(1+b^2)$.

---

> I can see how this part changed :$$sin(x)(tan(x)^2 =  sin(x)(1 + \tan^{2}(x))$$

I cannot however, since, using the same system as before, that amounts to saying $ab^2 = a(1+b^2)$. Doing the multiplication on the right-hand-side shows you that it is $a+ab^2$, which is obviously not $ab^2$.

Comment: Thank's Eevee, as soon as the required time has passed, I will marking your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: lol I actually thought $sin(1+tan^2) = sin(tan^2)$